# undefined method `join' for "product line":String

Tags: ruby

```
def nameize
  self.split.map do |word|
    if word.length > 3
      word.capitalize
    else
      word.downcase
    end
  end
  self.join(" ")
end
```

For some reason or another i have not been able to join my it back together does anyone know why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call join on an array, what map returns. I mean, you are losing what the map method is returning. Try this one

```
def nameize
  self.split.map do |word|
    if word.length > 3
      word.capitalize
    else
      word.downcase
    end
  end.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: My pleasure bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
def nameize
  self.split.map { |w| w.length > 3 ? w.capitalize : w.downcase }.join(" ")
end
```